# Should I include my master's gpa?

Tags: resume, internship, masters

I got a bad GPA in my masters first semester because of my bad handwritting(3.33) most of my classmates have a 4/4. I go to Rutgers University which is 34th ranked for computer science. I was wondering if I should omit my GPA since it's a bit low for masters. I am applying for summer internships.

I am an international student if it matters and the only work experience I have is at a fairly unknown company in India. But I have some really really awesome side projects.

Comment: I am hard-pressed to imagine how poor handwriting can meaningfully affect the GPA of a computer science master's student.  If you don't think the information will help you land the position, by all means omit it from your resume.

Comment: http://imgur.com/2Bgx005 Basically, my prof strucks off a lot of answers in my finals theory exam and had a very mean curve where even a 2 marks difference can cost you a grade. Coupled with that a B+ is 3.5 B is 3 and a C+ is 2.5 in my college. I ended up getting a C+, B+ and a A. I am afraid that if I don't list my GPA people will assume it's much worse like below 3!

Comment: @Aditya  "I was wondering if I should omit my GPA" - I'm guessing this is for a resume? You never said in your question. There's no general rule that a resume must include a GPA. However, if it's a form that's asking for your GPA, you probably should include it if asked.

Comment: I would recommend editing your question and take out any mention of handwriting, and the ranking of your school.  Instead of trying to remember if I've seen GPA's on resumes recently, I'm trying to figure out how penmanship makes or breaks a *CS* degree.

Answer (score 2):

The goal of the CV is to showcase what you know and can do well, not what you don't do well.

It's been a while since I've seen resumes with GPA listed for advanced degrees. I would omit it UNLESS it is specifically requested.

Sometimes the GPA information is requested on the separate employment application that the employer may have. In which case you should list the correct GPA on the application. But unless asked for, I encourage to omit it from the CV/resume.

I would, however, encourage you to make a reference to some of your (relevant) "awesome" side projects on the CV. This can be in a separate section, such as "Projects" or "Extracurricular" -- you can consult your university's Career Office for how best to integrate this experience into the CV.

Whichever way you do it, citing your role and accomplishments on these projects should illustrate your ability to apply your skills in practice and may help your candidacy to stand out. It can also be a good conversation piece during the interview, as an example of work you are particularly proud of or where you learned a lot about some aspect relevant to the position for which you are applying. Good luck!

Comment: When it comes to internships, I would imagine the GPA to be an important filtering criteria. I am pretty sure I lost getting calls for a number of internships because of my GPA! May be I shouldn't have listed it!! So without a GPA wouldn't it be more difficult to get some calls?

Comment: Indeed, internship positions announcements often ask for the GPA. I guess my point is that it does not necessarily need to be stated on the CV, unless requested. Also, not all GPAs are created equal, in a sense: depending on position, it may be possible (and more prudent) to state the GPA in only the courses directly applicable to a particular concentration or area (if an internship is in network security, it may be possible to list the GPA in courses directly related to that area, which may be higher than the overall program GPA).Thanks for your point inspiring further thinking/clarification.